# ADB fingerprint command stuck

Tags: android, adb, fingerprint

Try first time:

[image]

Try more than one time:

[image]

I try to use `adb` command to activate the fingerprint scanner on my `Android` virtural machine - `Nexus5X`. The strange thing is: when I just execute `adb -s emulator-5554 emu finger touch 1` for one time, there is no response. But after I keep trying many times (as shown in the picture), it works on my `AVM`. It just seems that `adb` command was very unstable.

Can anyone tell me what could probably be happening here?

Comment: BTW, I'm using this googlessample as the application. https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog

Comment: Any luck with the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have to connect to Telnet even if you're using Mac:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
```

then enter the cmd to authenticate

```
auth yourtoken
```

your authentication token is in this file '*/Users/yourname/.emulator_console_auth_token*'

then you have to register the finger print before to use the command. So go in Settings -> Security -> Fingerprint -> Add fingerprint and launch the command on terminal

```
finger touch 1
```

Now your fingerprint with ID 1 is enrolled and you can use it to authenticate

Comment: How does this solution work for emulator? How can you add fingerprint ?